# Ubuntu Server 22.04.01: Maldet, Successful login instantly closes, via SSH + directly

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, webserver

Problem: I ran a maldet scan and got a few hits, and now after rebooting, I cannot log in via SSH into my Ubuntu Server. That is, using the normal ssh login succeeds then instantly closes out. I  cannot log in through the physical computer either, so I am effectively locked out of my own server.

EDIT: I am thinking on this issue and I believe the recent maldet scan has suspended the user account, as I do remember considering suspension as viable within maldet config files. However this is the only account on the server. If this is the case, is there a way to unsuspend it or create a new user?

Comment: You should post your solution as answer and then accept it in stead of putting the answer in your question.

Comment: @LjmDullaart thanks Ive updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: For anyone who's also a new UNIX user and happened to set maldet's user suspension setting to 1, and got suspended with no way to access the user, do a few things:

1. The goal is to login with root access. Shutdown your pc, and start up while holding `esc` just right. Too long and it will load a `grub>` command line, and release too early it won't register. This will boot into a menu where you can choose advanced options.
2. Choose `recovery mode`
3. Choose `root` (this will log you in with root permissions)
4. From here, assuming you don't use C-panel, modify the text file `/etc/passwd`
5. From here you should be able to edit your user from /bin/false to `/bin/bash`
6. From here you can reboot and access your previously suspended user. Keep in mind this assumes user suspension is unwarranted.

Below is the relevant maldet config:

```
# The default suspend action for users wih hits
# Cpanel suspend or set shell /bin/false on non-Cpanel
# [NOTE: quarantine_hits=1 required]
# [0 = disabled, 1 = suspend account]
quarantine_suspend_user="0" # set this to 0 if you only have one user
```